# Java Split String Consecutive Delimiters

Tags: java, regex

I have a need to split a string that is passed in to my app from an external source. This String is delimited with a caret `"^"` and here is how I split the String into an Array

```
String[] barcodeFields = contents.split("\\^+");
```

[image]

This works fine except that some of the passed in fields are empty and I need to account for them. I need to insert either `""` or `"null"` or `"empty"` into any missing field.

And the missing fields have consecutive delimiters. How do I split a Java String into an array and insert a string such as `"empty"` as placeholders where there are consecutive delimiters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.split` leaves an empty string (`""`) where it encounters consecutive delimiters, as long as you use the right regex. If you want to replace it with `"empty"`, you'd have to do so yourself:

```
String[] split = barcodeFields.split("\\^");
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; ++i) {
    if (split[i].length() == 0) {
        split[i] = "empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what was happening and I have added a screenshot. Java sees "" as empty.

Comment: this fails, if there are trailing delimiters at the end. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58648034/274677

Answer (score 6):

The answer by [mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422776/mureinik) is quite close, but wrong in an important edge case: when the trailing delimiters are in the end. To account for that you have to use:

```
contents.split("\\^", -1)
```

E.g. look at the following code:

```
final String line = "alpha ^beta ^^^";
List<String> fieldsA = Arrays.asList(line.split("\\^"));
List<String> fieldsB = Arrays.asList(line.split("\\^", -1));
System.out.printf("# of fieldsA is: %d\n", fieldsA.size());
System.out.printf("# of fieldsB is: %d\n", fieldsB.size());
```

The above prints:

```
# of fieldsA is: 2
# of fieldsB is: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `^+` means one (or more consecutive) carat characters. Remove the plus

```
String[] barcodeFields = contents.split("\\^");
```

and it won't *eat* empty fields. You'll get (your requested) `""` for empty fields.

Comment: Hi Elliot, I added a screenshot, without the plus, it inserts "" but then Java sees that as an empty spot in the array so barcodeFields.size() gives 9 entries instead of 10 entries

Comment: Arrays have a `length` (not a `size()`). I'd also prefer `.isEmpty()` to `.length() == 0`

Answer (score -1):

The following results in `[blah, , bladiblah, moarblah]`:

```
    String test = "blah^^bladiblah^moarblah";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.split("\\^")));
```

Where the `^^` are replaced by a `""`, the empty String